AVX Memory write
Do SIMD operations generally not help out with memory write performance?
I created the following test to compare the results of writing a 16x16 block of uints a large number of times.
I am finding that the AVX version is marginally quicker. I thought this might be an L1/2/3 cache issue as 2048x2048x4 is a fairly chunky 16MB. So I tried with 256 instead of 2048, and it gives better performance (around 2x), but still not great.



Method
Mean
Error
StdDev
Median




Scalar
32.79 ms
0.528 ms
0.542 ms
32.87 ms


SIMD
27.36 ms
0.546 ms
1.428 ms
26.83 ms



public struct Point
{
    public float X;
    public float Y;
}

public class Test
{
    private const int Width = 2048;
    private uint[] _buffer = new uint[Width * Width];
    private const int PointSize = 16;

    private const int Points = 200_000;
    private Point[] _points = new Point[Points];

    [GlobalSetup]
    public void Setup()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < _buffer.Length; i++)
        {
            _buffer[i] = (uint)i;
        }

        var r = new Random(0);
        for (int i = 0; i < Points; i++)
        {
            _points[i] = new Point()
            {
                X = r.Next(0, Width - PointSize),
                Y = r.Next(0, Width - PointSize)
            };
        }
    }

    [Benchmark]
    public unsafe void Scalar()
    {
        int pointCount = _points.Length;

        fixed (uint* pBuffer = _buffer)
        fixed (Point* pPoints = _points)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < pointCount; ++i)
            {
                int x = (int)pPoints[i].X;
                int y = (int)pPoints[i].Y;

                for (int j = 0; j < PointSize; ++j)
                {
                    int yIndex = (y + j) * Width;

                    for (int k = 0; k < PointSize; ++k)
                    {
                        pBuffer[yIndex + x + k] = (uint)(j + k);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    [Benchmark]
    public unsafe void SIMD()
    {
        int pointCount = _points.Length;

        fixed (uint* pBuffer = _buffer)
        fixed (Point* pPoints = _points)
        {
            Vector256<uint> a = Vector256.Create<uint>(4);
            Vector256<uint> b = Vector256.Create<uint>(5);

            for (int i = 0; i < pointCount; ++i)
            {
                int x = (int)pPoints[i].X;
                int y = (int)pPoints[i].Y;

                for (int j = 0; j < PointSize; ++j)
                {
                    int yIndex = (y + j) * Width;

                    a.Store(pBuffer + yIndex + x);
                    b.Store(pBuffer + yIndex + x + 8);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

internal class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //var t = new Test();
        //t.Setup();
        //t.Scalar();

        BenchmarkRunner.Run<Test>();
    }
}


The compiler could have auto-vectorized your scalar code, maybe using just SSE2 or using a less than optimal AVX2 implementation.  Are these even doing the same work?  The SIMD version stores the same vectors at every pair of locations, but the scalar version stores (uint)(j + k), so the value stored isn't loop-invariant even for the inner loop.  This is easy to vectorize with a vector increment using vpaddd and a vector of [8,8,8,...], but IDK if the C# JIT is that clever.

As a guesstimate, 27ms / 200000 * 4GHz = 540 cycles per run of the outer loop (writing a 16x16 block). That's a lot even for 256 scalar stores. For 32 AVX stores it's even more of a lot. So, something other than the "base" throughput of the instructions is the bottleneck, and well you are randomly touching memory by design..

@PeterCordes user555045 I was basically just trying to figure out if SIMD can write to memory faster than scalar code. In my naivety, I was expecting maybe around 4x improvement, as I was visualizing it writing a 256bit vector 8x quicker (it would need to do this twice) than writing a uint value.

@creativergk that can happen but there are various complications. Depending on the amount of memory you're writing to and in what order, you're dealing with different throughput limitations and extra stuff (taking TLB misses etc). Even if stores are happening at the speed limit, there are other details - for example Zen4 can AFAIK perform two scalar stores per cycle (up to 2x64-bit), but not two SIMD stores (half a 512-bit store, one 256-bit store, also only one 128-bit store which is not even more than you get with 64-bit scalar stores)
